# Коли і через що українці почали масово вимовляти «щ» як «шь»?

Tags: росіянізм, фонетика

У своїй праці Микола Погрібний стверджує, що у літературній мові «щ» слід вимовляти як тверде «шч», однак в усній мові побутує вимова «шь». У праці «Пошук українського слова» Караванський не згадував будь-якого звʼязку з упливом радянського союзу.

Тож коли і через що українці почали «шьокати»?

Comment: Як хлоп, який ріс у Хмельницькій області, вперше чую, що українці "вимошляють щ як шь". Я і російською-то завжди "шчокав"...

Answer (score 0):

Не існує певного моменту, коли «українці почали».

Існує континуум діалектів. Які плавно перетікають один в одного. Це справедливе твердження для будь-якої живої мови (такої, що розвивається).

Східні діалекти довше були як під *природнім* впливом — спочатку угро-фінських мов, а потім і офіційного московського «русского язика»,
а в часи окупації — і під *примусовою* русифікацією.

Тому саме у східних діалектах `[ ʃ t͡ʃ ]` більше схиляється до злиття і палаталізації в `[ɕː]`. Подробиці тут (анлійськов): [What differences are there in the difficulty of learning Ukrainian and Russian to a very basic level?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2581/60)

Те саме стосується діапазонів `[ ɕ ʃ ʂ ]` і `[ ʑ ʒ ʐ ]`, про що (англійськов) викладено тут:
[Do Russian-Ukrainian bilinguals or speakers immersed in both languages switch between the pair [ʂ ʐ] and [ʃ ʒ] when they switch between the languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/37944/1009)

---

#### Висновок

У будь-якому випадку, можна сміливо стверджувати, що протягом усього часу розвитку української мови *деякі* українці «шьокали».

Comment: А зараз «шьокання» це діалект чи помилка вимови внаслідок впливу російської за радянського союзу?